# Importing Android Studio Project into GitHub

Tags: android, git, github, intellij-idea, version-control

I have a project made in Android Studio that I wish to put into a GitHub repository. I used "Import into version control" -> "Share project on GitHub". Android Studio then made an empty repository on my GitHub account with the name that I specified. I simply cannot make an initial commit now that the repository is there. When I use VCS -> Git -> Commit file, it simply pops up a window that says "Nothing to commit.". I've tried making a new dummy file, and yet it still thinks there have been no changes. I've also tried selecting all of the files and using the "add" button, but this appears to do nothing whatsoever. How can I get this project on GitHub? My desire, specifically, is literally just to somehow commit my project in Android Studio into this GitHub repository it has created for me so that I can collaborate on this project with some friends. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing to commit, Android Studio has already commited all your files *locally*. Now you need to `VCS > Git > Push` to upload your commits to your GitHub repository.

Comment: I should have mentioned it says "nothing to push" when I do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up happening is I just created a new project, copied and pasted all of my code in, and then used the "Share Project on GitHub" button again. This time, for whatever reason, it worked seamlessly.